# How to play games on Nvidia Card in Ununtu 14.04

Tags: games, nvidia-optimus, 14.04

I want to play only games on Nvidia Graphics Card and render my desktop with Intel Grphics Card.
How do I add application profiles to Nvidia X server settings.

Comment: Why has nobody given any answer ??